# Add rows and data

Tags: javascript, html-table

So currently I can add rows with this code:

```
function addRow(){
    var tableRef = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

  // Insert a row in the table at row index 0
  var newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);

  // Insert a cell in the row at index 0
  var newCell  = newRow.insertCell(0);

  // Append a text node to the cell
  var newText  = document.createTextNode('New row')
  newCell.appendChild(newText);
}
```

Here is my table:

```
<table id="myTable" border="2px">
    <tbody>
    <td>
    Module 1
    </td>
    <td>
    Introduction
    </td>

    <td id="info">
    </td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <div id="button"><a href="javascript:addRow();"> Add Another Row </a></div> 
    </td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is how I add data to the row:

```
function showChoices()
{
  //retrieve data
  var selLanguage = document.getElementById("productchoice3");
  //set up output string
  var result="<ul> \n";

  //step through options
  for (i = 0; i < selLanguage.length; i++)
  {
   //examine current option
   currentOption = selLanguage[i];

   //print it if it has been selected
    if (currentOption.selected == true)
    {
   console.log(currentOption.label);
   result += " <li>" + currentOption.label + "<br>" + currentOption.value + "<\/li> \n";
    } // end if
  } // end for loop

  //finish off the list and print it out
  result += "<\/ul> \n";

  output = document.getElementById("info");
  output.innerHTML = result;
  document.getElementById('info').style.display='block';
}
```

What I want to do is have the "add another row" move down each time I click it, so I can add infinite rows, and have a way to add data to the newest row that was created.

Comment: What is the problem? I can see you are already adding some text content to the cell.

Comment: What would be the key by which the user / the code know which row to add data to?

Comment: You can return `newCell` or `newRow` from this function, then associate that return value with your button or select list somehow... but without seeing how this is called, and how your button action works, it's hard to say anything concrete.

Comment: I explained my question a little better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily add an id to the row, by doing:

```
var newRow = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);
newRow.id = "whateverYouWant";
```

Comment: that would work for one row, but if I add multiple rows, it would keep giving the same Id

Comment: You can set the id to a variable that you change for every row

Comment: one of the ways im thinking of would be to just have a variable that is the ID and increment it each time i add a new row. I might just be derping but how would I keep the value in between executions? just make the variable global?

Comment: Making the variable global should work for that, yes.